# How do I find out which Registrar a domain is registered through?

Tags: domain-registrar

I'm hoping to backorder a domain that looks promissing. I've [read](http://www.mikeindustries.com/blog/archive/2005/03/how-to-snatch-an-expiring-domain) that if it's through Network Solutions then you should use SnapNames b/c it automatically does the auctioning/rselling for NS.

Answer (score 2):

Doing a whois shows which regsitrar I have (GoDaddy.com):

> [Querying whois.verisign-grs.com]
>   [Redirected to whois.godaddy.com]
>    Querying whois.godaddy.com]
>   [whois.godaddy.com]
>   The data contained
>   in GoDaddy.com, Inc.'s WhoIs database,
>   while believed by the company to be
>   reliable, is provided "as is" with no
>   guarantee or warranties regarding its
>   accuracy.  This information is
>   provided for the sole purpose of
>   assisting you in obtaining information
>   about domain name registration
>   records. Any use of this data for any
>   other purpose is expressly forbidden
>   without the prior written permission
>   of GoDaddy.com, Inc.  By submitting an
>   inquiry, you agree to these terms of
>   usage and limitations of warranty.  In
>   particular, you agree not to use this
>   data to allow, enable, or otherwise
>   make possible, dissemination or
>   collection of this data, in part or in
>   its entirety, for any purpose, such as
>   the transmission of unsolicited
>   advertising and and solicitations of
>   any kind, including spam.  You further
>   agree not to use this data to enable
>   high volume, automated or robotic
>   electronic processes designed to
>   collect or compile this data for any
>   purpose, including mining this data
>   for your own personal or commercial
>   purposes.
>
> Please note: the registrant of the
>   domain name is specified in the
>   "registrant" field.  In most cases,
>   GoDaddy.com, Inc.  is not the
>   registrant of domain names listed in
>   this database.
>
> Registrant:    John Conde
>
> Registered through: GoDaddy.com,
>   Inc. (http://www.godaddy.com)
>   Domain Name: JOHNCONDE.NET
>
> Domain servers in listed order:
>         NS795.WEBSITEWELCOME.COM
>         NS796.WEBSITEWELCOME.COM
>
> For complete domain details go to: 
>   http://who.godaddy.com/whoischeck.aspx?Domain=JOHNCONDE.NET

This worked for all of the domains I checked with various registrars.